# Automatic field translation delphi 10.2

Tags: android, delphi, translation

So my question is: is there a way to create a class or something that translates automatically the TLabels, TText of an android application with Delphi after that the user chooses the language wanted? Or is there a solution with the auto-translate ?

I don't want to use the resource DLL Wizard or something that needs internet cause the tablet i'm working on won't be connected to internet.

I'm still a beginner in Delphi and still lost.
I'm sorry in advance if there is any information needed that I didn't provide.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a component that you can use. [TLang](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Berlin/en/FMXTLang_(Delphi))

Comment: thank you so much for the fast answer but i want something that translates automatically the text fields without me having to write the translation for every field because i have a lot of fields in my app

Comment: Considering the vastness of each and every human language, that goal will ultimately fail. You will have to translate yourself, of with the help of professional translators, if you want your application to be understood, and not show ridiculous gibberish. Especially if you want to make money with it.

Comment: @Samar You said that the internet is not usable. If not there should be a Dictionary with AI to translate texts for you, and I don't know if there is any offline solution or not. But if you decide to use something like google translate you may get an acceptable result but not the best result, because even google did a very nice job on translating the result still does with the machine. If your program is not too heavy I recommend using that TLang component.